# How do I transfer a resource group from a disabled subscription?

Tags: azure, subscription

We had a BizSpark subscription which expired. I had assumed it would just start billing me, but instead the actual Azure subscription became disabled with a status of "Disabled by administrator." After checking with the actual administrator of our BizSpark account, he did not disable it and cannot reactivate it. (Seriously you'd think we could just type in our billing info and move on... way to go MS!)

So I figured I'd create a new subscription and transfer the resource groups to the new subscription... only to get an error stating:

Resources cannot be moved from disabled subscriptions.

Because that makes perfect sense, right? So does anyone know a way to get the resources transferred so I don't have to recreate everything and lose the database info?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Raise a ticket with Microsoft billing support within Azure Portal and explain the situation. They should reactivate your subscription by adding the necessary credits for 1-day operation. That's enough time for you to migrate the resources, assuming these resources are movable. That happened to me before, but I can't attest they will do the same in your case though. If you are willing to pay for the rest of the month using a credit card then all you have to do is to remove the spending limit and ask support for reactivation. In this case, you don't need to migrate resources.

Comment: We have a support ticket into them for the BizSpark transition already and it's taking days for each reply from them. Was hoping for an option that didn't depend on their support... sounds like there isn't one?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Once the subscription is disabled, there's no other way to enable it other than asking support. Shouldn't take days though.

Comment: He finally got back to us this morning.